# Create X/Y percentage formula based on two example values

Tags: percentages

I'm trying to figure out the formula of X to Y based on the following two examples:

If $X = 78.6$ then $Y = 3.8 \%$

If $X = 72.9$ then $Y = 4.3\%$

As X decreases Y raises. I'd like to be able to calculate:

What is $X$ if $Y = 15\%$ ?

What is $X$ if $Y = 12\%$ ?

What is $X$ if $Y = 10\%$ ?

Comment: you can have infinitely many different functions that fit that relationship. Do you want a linear function, i.e. just a straight line?

Comment: Yes just a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

To find some line $ax+b$ that fits the two data points you solve the system
$$
78.6a + b = 3.8\\
72.9a+b = 4.3
$$
which gives
$$
a \approx -\frac{1}{11.4}, \quad b \approx 10.7
$$
So you have the line
$$
y = -\frac{1}{11.4}x + 10.7
$$
So for example to find $x$ such that $y=10$ you just plug in for $y$
$$
10 = -\frac{1}{11.4}x + 10.7
$$
and solve for $x$ to get
$$
x = 7.98
$$